# Magento not saving custom product attributes after version upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, attributes, product-attribute, upgrade

I upgraded a Magento 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.3.4 and now (three months later) I have some troubles with custom product attributes.

1) One of them is dropdown. I select the option, I save the product and the attribute is well saved. But when I edit the product again, the current attribute option is not selected. When I edit the product, the dropdown field is blank, with no option selected.

2) Another attribute is text field. I replace the old text with a new one, but after I save it, the old text continue to appear, so I guess it doesn't save the attribute at all.

There are no javascript/php errors.

Any idea/sugestion will help. Thanks.

**EDIT**

As far as I've tested, this issues affect only the products from the old website. These products were exported from the old website and later imported to the new website (Using Magento's System/ Export and later System/ Import functionality). I can edit other attributes without any issue.

I wasn't able to reproduce these issues when creating new products on the website.

Comment: tried reindexing?

Comment: Yes, everything was successfully reindexed but the problem persists. Logs are enabled, there is no related message in the system.log and exception.log files.

Comment: is this issue only with those two attributes?

Comment: Yes, and they affect only the old products. These products were exported from the old website and imported to the new one. I edited my initial question and added more details.

Comment: @Pascut this is happening for old attributes which you import , AM I right ?

Comment: Yes. You're right. Any idea how can I fix this?